# how to embed multiple events on function?

Tags: jquery

I'm having like this:

```
$(selector).on('click hover', function() { /*code to be executed*/ });
```

but only `click` is triggered but not `hover`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `hover` event. jQuery's [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function listens for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` to conveniently bind two event handlers.

If you want your function to be called when the mouse enters the object, do

```
$(selector).on('click mouseenter', function(){/*code to be executed*/});
```

Comment: @Mr_Green That's a function, not an event. The pseudo event doesn't exist any more.

Comment: yes, from hover jquery docs, "_The .hover() **method** binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events. You can use it to simply apply behavior to an element during the time the mouse is within the element._"

Answer (score 1):

> **Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9**: The name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine `event.type` to determine whether the event is `mouseenter` or `mouseleave`. Do not confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the `.hover()` method, which accepts one or two functions.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: +1 this explains exactly what is the issue. dystroy's answer is also good though :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#target").hover(function(){
  $(this).click();
}).click(function(){
  //common function
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can also manage like this:

```
var ch= function () {
    // code to be executed
}
$(selector).click(ch).hover(ch);
```

Comment: hmm.. what was your question actually? I thought it was "why _hover_ is not working in multiple event bindings?".

Comment: No hover and click was not working so I said that I can manage those events with provided answer function..... and you are right what you've thought.